# How do I show a of list elements of an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a large array of 465 items, with each item having five elements. E.g.

```
const fixture = {id: '955dc591ce70', title: 'Liverpool vs Arsenal', date: '2022-03-18', start: '2022-03-18T19:35:00', end: '2022-03-18T21:05:00', competition: 'Premier League'}
```

I want to ouput an array of just the competitions for each game. I have tried  `console.log(this.state.fixtures.competition)` but no success. How can i acheiev this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample on a fiddle link possibly, so we can look into what sort of data you have? Or even on here will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this outputting to console

```
this.state.fixtures.forEach(fixture => console.log(fixture.competition));
```

Comment: This is outputting '413 ~ Premier League' and '65 ~Champions League'. How would i make it output the entire array e.g 
0. Premier League
1. Premier League 
2. Premier League 
3. Champions League 
4. Premier League

Comment: const array = [];
this.state.fixtures.forEach(fixture => array.push(fixture.competition));
console.log(array);

This just adds those values to an empty array then you print that to console. Not sure if this is what you wanted